# Storing relation in RavenDB without manually storing the related documents?

Tags: c#, ravendb

## TLDR:

Is it possible to:

1. store a document (Article) with a relation (Tags) in one `Store`/`StoreAsync` call to RavenDB, but into separate collections?
2. then fetch the parent document (Article) including the related documents (Tags) in one query (without including/loading the tags separately)?

## Explanation

AFAIK the only way to store data to RavenDB which have a relation into separate collections is to store them individually. When you read the data, you need to `Include` the related documents and call `Load` to get them.

I wonder if there is a way to simplify this by storing and querying Articles and related Tags in one go.

I have a idea how I wish it would work (but it does not), as well a working but cumbersome example.

The examples below are split into these steps

1. POCOs
2. Storing data
3. Index definition
4. Querying the index

I put the broken-but-I-wish-it-would-work and the working examples next to each other. I think it is easier to understand it that way.

### POCOs

**broken-but-I-wish-it-would-work**

```csharp
namespace Articles
{
    public class ArticlePersistance
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<TagPersistance> Tags { get; set; } // Specify TagPersistance here
    }

    [DearRavenDBStoreToSeparateCollectionPlease] // Does not exist
    public class TagPersistance
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**working**

```csharp
namespace Articles
{
    public class ArticlePersistance
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<string> Tags { get; set; } // Specify string here
    }

    public class TagPersistance
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Storing data

**broken-but-I-wish-it-would-work**
Storing `ArticlePersistance` and `TagPersistance` into their own collections with one call to `StoreAsync`. AFAIK this stores the Article and Tags into the same collection.

```csharp
var tag = new TagPersistance() { Name = "Tag1" };
var article = new ArticlePersistance()
{
    Title = "aaa",
    Tags = new List<TagPersistance> { tag } // Embed the full Tag here
};
await session.StoreAsync(article); // Only one call to StoreAsync
await session.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**working**
Storing the Article and Tags separately:

```csharp
var tag = new TagPersistance() { Name = "Tag1" };
await session.StoreAsync(tag); // Store Tag separately

var article = new ArticlePersistance()
{
    Title = "aaa",
    Tags = new List<string> { tag.Id } // Embed only the tag id
};
await session.StoreAsync(article);

await session.SaveChangesAsync();
```

### Index definition

**broken-but-I-wish-it-would-work**
Index on `ArticlePersistance` which stores the full Tag objects

```csharp
public class Articles_Test : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ArticlePersistance>
{
    public Articles_Test()
    {
        Map = articles => 
               from article in articles
               let tags = article.Tags.Select(t => LoadDocument<TagPersistance>(t)) // Load the related Tags
               select new
               {
                   Title = article.Title,
                   Tags = tags // Store the full Tag objects here
               };
    }
}
```

**working**
Index which holds only the Tag names, not the full Tag objects:

```csharp
public class Articles_Test : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ArticlePersistance>
{
    public Articles_Test()
    {
        Map = articles => 
               from article in articles
               let tags = article.Tags.Select(t => LoadDocument<TagPersistance>(t)) // Load the related Tags
               select new
               {
                   Title = article.Title,
                   Tags = tags.Select(t => t.Name) // Store only the Tag name
               };
    }
}
```

### Querying the index

**broken-but-I-wish-it-would-work**
Finally querying the index and getting the article with the tags back.
I hoped for fetching the Article and the Tags in one go here

```csharp
// This does not work
var article = await session
    .Query<ArticlePersistance, Articles_Test>()
    .Where(a => a.Title == "aaa")
    .ToListAsync();
```

**working**
This is working, but cumbersome.
You need to care about the relation between Article and Tags which could already be specified in the Index definition.

```csharp
var article = await session
    .Query<ArticlePersistance, Articles_Test>()
    .Where(a => a.Title == "aaa")
    .Include(t => t.Tags) // Include the tags
    .ToListAsync();
// Query the tags separatelly
var tags = await session.LoadAsync<TagPersistance>(article.SelectMany(a => a.Tags));
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but maybe this Query can give you an idea. 
The RawQuery returns an object that contains full documents.
Look at the example in this section: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-stream-query-results#stream-related-documents

Comment: Do I understand the example correctly, that it does not use an index? Which could be really slow...

Comment: yes, but this dynamic query triggers the creation of an Auto-Index, so you will have an index after all. A simple Auto-index explanation is here: https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/auto-indexes/auto-map-index1